# I want to modify My Screen to Drawer in React Native

Tags: reactjs, native

I want to Convert my below code or want to modify it so I can be able to Show Drawer please I am new to react Native help me. thanks in advance.
I want to navigate This Drawer from Other Screen

I am writing this Because I cant post Question =  I want to Convert my below code or want to modify it so I can be able to Show Drawer please I am new to react Native help me. thanks in advance.
I want to navigate This Drawer from Other Screen
I want to Convert my below code or want to modify it so I can be able to Show Drawer please I am new to react Native help me. thanks in advance.
I want to navigate This Drawer from Other Screen
I want to Convert my below code or want to modify it so I can be able to Show Drawer please I am new to react Native help me. thanks in advance.
I want to navigate This Drawer from Other Screen

This Is My Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TextInput, View } from "react-native";
import Slider from "react-native-slider";
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Foundation } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {RoleLogin} from './Browse'
import Browse from './Browse'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { Divider, Button, Block, Text, Switch } from "../components";
import { theme, mocks } from "../constants";

class Settings extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      profile: {},
      error: [],
      // data: [],
      roles: "",
      username:"",
      password:"",
      lading: false,
      title:"",
      data:"",
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ profile: this.props.profile });
  }

  handleEdit(name, text) {
    const { profile } = this.state;
    profile[name] = text;

    this.setState({ profile });
  }

  toggleEdit(name) {
    const { editing } = this.state;
    this.setState({ editing: !editing ? name : null });
  }
  renderEdit(name) {
    const { profile, editing } = this.state;

    if (editing === name) {
      return (
        <TextInput
          defaultValue={profile[name]}
          onChangeText={text => this.handleEdit([name], text)}
        />
      );
    }

    return <Text bold>{profile[name]}</Text>;
  }

  render() {
    const { profile, editing, roles , username} = this.state;
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const data = navigation.getParam('data');

    return (

      <Block> 

        <Block flex={false} row center space="between" style={styles.header}>
          <Text h1 bold>
            Settings
          </Text>
          <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Browse")}>
            <Image source={profile.avatar} style={styles.avatar} />
          </Button>
        </Block> 

         <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}> 

          <Block style={styles.inputs}>

            <Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block style={{ flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                </Text>
                <AntDesign name="user" size={24} color="black" />
                {this.renderEdit("username")}
              </Block>
              <Text
                medium
                secondary
                onPress={() => this.toggleEdit("username")}
              >
                {editing === "username" ? "Save" : "Edit"}
              </Text>
            </Block>
    
            <Divider margin={[theme.sizes.base, theme.sizes.base * 1]} />
            
            {data == "delectus aut autem" &&
            <Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block style={{ flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}></Text>
                <Foundation name="page-copy" size={24} color="black" />
                <Text bold style={{paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>Customer Report</Text>
              </Block>
            </Block>
            }      
            
          </Block>
        </ScrollView>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}
Settings.defaultProps = {
  profile: mocks.profile
};

export default Settings;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  },
  avatar: {
    height: theme.sizes.base * 1.2,
    width: theme.sizes.base * 2.2
  },
  inputs: {
    marginTop: theme.sizes.base * 0.7,
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  },
  inputRow: {
    alignItems: "flex-end"
  },
  sliders: {
    marginTop: theme.sizes.base * 0.7,
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2

  },
  thumb: {
    width: theme.sizes.base,
    height: theme.sizes.base,
    borderRadius: theme.sizes.base,
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary
  },
  toggles: {
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: did you try 'navigation.openDrawer();'?

Comment: I do not Know where to Add And what to do please help me. if possible modify my code and paste it again. thanks in advance

Comment: try add to any your event to check like onpress....

Comment: Like @DonOzOn said you could do [navigation.openDrawer()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/#opening-and-closing-drawer). We can't really help you further if you aren't more specific on what you actually want to do and what is not working. Do you want to open the drawer when the `Settings` component is rendered, open the drawer on click, etc... Also what does your navigation structure look like?

Comment: Yes I want to open the drawer when the Settings component is rendered

Comment: Then you can put `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` in `componentDidMount`.